# Размещение вопросов в группе

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица db(базы) и таблица category (категории).таблица категорий имеет поля поля id Name ParentId. Что б можно было разместить вложенные категории.
суть в том-нужно создать виртуальную базу данных(назовем это базой данных),которая будет содержать категории,а к категориям будут прикреплены вопросы для тестирования.
пример выглядит так: 
база:экзамен 2016 Терапия-категории: кардиология,гастроэнтерология и к их айдишникам прикреплены вопросы.
ну вот только как быть,если я хочу прикрепить вопрос не к категории,а к базе данных?как бы "общий вопрос",но не создавая еще такую категорию. Вообщем интересна структура бд в данной ситуации,что б доступны были оба варианта.

Comment: В вопросе разрешаете в поле id категории NULL и все такие записи считаете общими

Comment: @Mike, тогда вопрос станет общим для всех "баз". А нужно, я так понимаю, чтобы он был общим в пределах одной "базы".

Comment: Да, точно, слова "база" смутили и я их в расчет не принимал... Тогда недостаточно данных. Набор категорий один на всех или у каждой "базы" свой набор категорий ?

Comment: У каждой базы свой набор категорий(либо вообще без категорий,но тогда вопрос прикрепляется к базе,а не к категории).

Comment: А один вопрос может быть в нескольких категориях?

Comment: вообще,на данном этапе-я сделал связующую таблицу с полями QuestionId,CategoryId тоесть может в разных быть,но практически скорее всего будет только в одной

Comment: Тогда, как вариант, можно изменить эту таблицу, чтобы она была (QuestionId,CategoryId,dbId), где CategoryId и dbId обе nullable, причём CategoryId/dbId должно быть либо/либо. Если одно указано, другое должно быть NULL и наоборот. Или разложить это по двум таблицам, одна как у вас была, вторая (QuestionId,dbId).

Comment: Я бы предложил вообще слить вместе "базы" и "категории". Категории сделать древовидными. Корневая категория "экзамен 2016" и по ней пошли подкатегории. Опять же дерево удобно что бы под категорией "Терапия" сделать уже специальности. И в вопросе id категории любого уровня.